# Error convert in Java Timestamp, not proper transform from Mysql 8.26

Tags: java, mysql

I'm trying to extract a vector of object form general case using a string to timestamp conversion.
In this case, the mysql value has the following format: "2022-06-29 10:08:22"
But when I printed the String, it has the following format: "2022-06-29T10:08:22". Here, we note that the output includes a "T" character. When I try to convert using the timestamp I get an error.

Code:

```
data = new Object[0][0];   
data[0][0]=rs.getObject(0);    TimeStamp
createTimestampt= Timestamp.valueOf((String)data[0][0]));
```

In this case, is a outdate of class java.sql.Timestamp?. or Where i missted?

Note: Ojbect rs is an instance of java.sql.ResultSet. For obvious reasons not to include all the code. But the essence of the problem was discussed.

Thank you

Thanks

Comment: What *exactly precisely* is the data type of your column in MySQL?

Comment: The type of the field is DateTime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## tl;dr

You neglected to mention the data type of your column. So I cannot tell you which of these to use.

Either:

```
OffsetDateTime odt = myResultSet.getObject( … , OffsetDateTime.class ) ;
```

… or:

```
LocalDateTime ldt = myResultSet.getObject( … , LocalDateTime.class ) ;
```

## *java.time*

Never use the legacy class `Timestamp`. It was years ago supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes. Specifically, replaced by `Instant` and `OffsetDateTime`.

JDBC 4.2 and later requires that a JDBC driver support the *java.time* classes.

## `OffsetDateTime`

Assuming you are accessing a column of a data type akin to the SQL standard type `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`, retrieve a `OffsetDateTime`.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = myResultSet.getObject( … , OffsetDateTime.class ) ;
```

Writing to the database.

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , odt ) ;
```

## `LocalDateTime`

If you are accessing a database column of a type akin to the SQL standard type `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE`, use `LocalDateTime` class.

## Formats

You said:

> mysql value has the following format: "2022-06-29 10:08:22"

No, not accurate. A database column of a date-time type is not text so it has no format.

What you are seeing is text generated to value represented in that column.

If you retrieve a `OffsetDateTime` as directed above, no text is involved.

You can generate text from your `OffsetDateTime` object.

- For standard ISO 8601 format, call `toString`.
- For a localized format, use `DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime`.
- For a custom format, use `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern`.

All of these text generation approaches have been covered many many times on Stack Overflow. Search to learn more.

You said:

> Here, we note that the output includes a "T" character.

That format with the `T` is defined by the ISO 8601 standard.